# WPF: What's the right way to display very large data (out of memory) in a data grid control(RadGridView)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, radgridview, large-data

I'm trying to implement a sniffer tool (just like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)). I plan to display the captured traffic into a 
data grid(eg. RadGridView) row by row. User can view all the rows by dragging a vertical scrollbar. And user can sort and filter the data.

One problem I can see is that:
The captured traffic can be very large, so I may need to cache old data into disk and only display the latest n row by default. And when user dragging the vertical scrollbar to view old data, I need to load the old data from disk.

**Is my approach the right way for this case? If yes, how to implement it in detail? If no, what's the right way?**

Comment: Although the data grid provides *UI* virtualization, that's no help here. It sounds like you need some kind of *data* virtualization solution. Take a look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization

Comment: @AndrewStephens the article seems what I need. I'll look at it in detail later. Thanks!